# sending information into an IP through Html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using making a web based microcontroller and now I want to send some sort of data to my microcontroller through a Html page .
can I do that in a raw Html file or I should use other programs like javascript or perhaps php
can every one give me some simple source code

Comment: What web based microcontroller are you using? Do you know what web server it has installed, if any? What operating system is it running? More details please! But yes, assuming your microcontroller has the appropriate software and connection, you can send data to it with just a basic html page. However, the hard part will be setting up the microcontroller to receive that information and act upon it. Also, what do you want it to do with that information?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way i could imagine is making a button, with a PHP script attached, and that PHP Execute a compiled binary that does something in your microcontroller.
Example:
index.html

```
<html>    
  <body>
    <Form Name ="form1" Method ="POST" ACTION = "send.php">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Login">
  </body>
</html>
```

send.php:

```
<?php 
    echo "<html><body>";
    echo "The microcontroller say:"+exec('microcontrollerbinary $_POST['fname']');
    echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

Your microcontroller should have a binary who read first argument from command line 'fname' and printout something

Comment: can somebody give some javascript code that I can recieve information in Html page and send to to a specific Ip like 192.168.1.250